# Reputation for accepted answer not received, profile out of sync with log on /reputation

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39866437/how-to-send-message-to-multiple-numbers-using-service/39867626#39867626).

> [image: screenshot of reputation]

According to this I received **+25** Reputation on the answer.  My previous 
reputation was **492** which sums up to **517**, but my reputation increased to only **502**.

That means I only got the reputation for the upvote, so where is the remaining **15** reputation for the acceptance of the answer?

The log at /reputation shows that I should have **517** reputation, so my profile is out of sync:

```
  2  39726995 (10)
  1  39749521 (2)
  2  39773219 (10)
  -- 2016-09-29 rep +22   = 447       
  -- 2016-10-01 rep 0     = 447       
  -- 2016-10-03 rep 0     = 447       
  1  39846026 (15)
  2  39846026 (10)
  2  39846026 (10)
  2  39846026 (10)
  -- 2016-10-04 rep +45   = 492       
  2  39867626 (10)
  1  39867626 (15)
  -- 2016-10-05 rep +25   = 517       
  -- 2016-10-06 rep 0     = 517       
  -- 2016-10-07 rep 0     = 517
```

Comment: Can you go to the bottom of http://stackoverflow.com/reputation and copy the most recent entries? Looking at your profile, start with September 29th.

Comment: I can see at your link it is properly updated to 517 but I didnt understood how you got these stats and why mine is not updated

Comment: It could be a bug, it could be caching gone wrong, or something else entirely. Can you include the lines in your question here? Might help us figure out what's up.

Comment: I wonder if someone happened to unaccept an answer.

Comment: I have given the link above to my answer above,    here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39866437/how-to-send-message-to-multiple-numbers-using-service/39867626#39867626

Comment: Can I know when my reputation will be updated. Thanx

Comment: @AshishShukla Can you add the output of the /reputation page like I requested?

Comment: Thanks for the data. I've edited the title to include this info and retagged the post as [meta-tag:bug].